# Cordova Facebook Connect Plugin: Android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager

Tags: android, windows, eclipse, facebook, sdk

Been having issues in eclipse whilst working on an Android Application. The application requires the Facebook SDK & Phonegap's BarcodeScanner plugin to function. Now Previously I've had this whole project working absolutely fine on a Mac using the ADT bundle. The issues have arisen since trying to bring this project over to a Windows Machine.

So I've imported the previous project (by copying the parent directory) to sit on my computer, and re-downloaded the Facebook SDK and Phonegap plugins. I've set both the Facebook SDK and Barcodescanner as library's as I had done on the Mac version; made sure they all pointed to the right location. I've sorted some expected bugs expected from Eclipse when you import projects/library in.

Now the app runs, and when it gets to the Facebook Login I get a "Cordova Facebook Connect plugin fail on Login!android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadCastManager" in a alert window, and won't let me do anything. I'm so confused cause this project and setup was working fine on the Mac and nothing has changed except for locations of files which I've adjusted.

"VFY: Unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/support/v4/app/fragment;)"
"Could not find method android.support.v4.content.localbroadcastmanager.getInstance,referenced from method com.facebook.session.postactiveSessionaction"

Above is the only reference I can see (in logcat) to the Androidsupport files not being found ! Any help could be greatly appreciated, especially if anyone else has moved a project from different OS's

Comment: Did you import the support package in eclipse? (android tools, don't remember exactly the name of the item but run "how to import the support package in eclipse" and you'll find it)

Answer (score 2):

I just removed the file android-support-v4.jar from project's lib folder and it works! (but before you must import the FacebookSDK folder)

Answer (score 1):

Go to the facebook SDK folder and then copy "android-support-v4.jar" from the folder libs
and past it to the "libs" folder of your project.

Comment: I actually found with a newer version of Eclipse/SDK you can just right click a project and add Android Support, which then installs Support 13 which comes with the needed Android-Support-v4.jar. Thanks for the help though.